# File letter counter errors

Tags: java, loops

Write a program that asks the user to enter the name of a file, and then asks the user to enter a character. The program should count and display the number of times that the specified character appears in the file.

My problem is that length and charAt on lines 24 and 25 error, and I'm not sure what to do in order to get the program to run.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class challenge6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String string;
        char character;
        int count = 0; 

        File file =   new File("./file.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        input.hasNextLine();

        while (input.hasNextLine())
            System.out.println(input.nextLine());

        System.out.println("enter name of a char");
        character = input.next().charAt(0);    

        for(int i=0; i < input.length(); i++)
        {    if(input.charAt(i) == character)
            count++;
        }

        System.out.println(count);}}
```

Comment: and do you have a question?

Comment: So, what's the issue?

Comment: `input.nextLine()` is reading only one line and it is not even saving the line in a variable.  `input.lenght` - does this method exists?

Comment: length and charAt on lines 24 and 25 error, and I'm not sure what to do in order to get the program to run.

Comment: p.s. just learning loops, was hoping someone could explain this code to me, and fix it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: For a start assign `input.nexLine ()` to a String variable.  `length` should be the method of the `String` variable.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way would be to utilize the `String::replace` method to replace char with blank and check to string length before and after.  You also need to loop all through your file

```
File f = new File("c:/tmp/file.txt");
Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
int count = 0;
String charToFind = "a";

while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = input.nextLine();
    int len = line.length();
    line = line.replace(charToFind, "");
    count += len - line.length();
}

System.out.format("There were %d occurrences found%n", count);
input.close();
```